# Перезапись значения в датафрейме

Tags: python, dataframe

Всем привет!
Первый фрейм:

```
import pandas as pd, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],
                   'column2': [100, 101, 102]})
```

Выход:

```
  column1  column2
0   name1      100
1   name2      101
2   name3      102
```

Второй фрейм:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'column1': ['name1', 'name2', 'name3'],  
                   'column2': [1000, 2000, 3000]})
```

Выход:

```
  column1  column2
0   name1     1000
1   name2     2000
2   name3     3000
```

Задача:
В df записать:

- если column1 = name1 значение name1 из column2 из df2
- для остальных сохранить изначальное значение

Хочу получить df:

```
  column1  column2
0   name1      1000
1   name2      101
2   name3      102
```

Мои решения.
Первое решение:

```
df['Column2'] = df.apply(lambda x: (df.merge(df2, how = 'left', left_on=['column1'], right_on=['column1'])) if x['column1'] == 'name1' else x['column2'], axis=1)
```

Выдает:

```
  column1  column2                                            Column2
0   name1      100    column1  column2_x  column2_y
0   name1     ...
1   name2      101                                                101
2   name3      102                                                102
```

во-первых создает новую колонку, а не записывает в уже существующую, во-вторых при соблюдении условия записывается весь датафрейм, а не только значение "3000"

Второе решение:

```
new_results = {}
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    row["column_2"] = df.merge(df2, how = 'left', left_on=['column1'], right_on=['column1']) if row["column1"] == 'name1' else row["column2"]
    new_results[index] = dict(row)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(new_results, orient='index')
```

результат такой же как у первого :(
Если есть возможность показать решение обоими способами, понимаю, что проблема где-то в merge, но не могу понять как ее решить

Comment: `df.loc[(df['column1'] == 'name1'), 'column2'] = df2.loc[(df2['column1'] == 'name1'), 'column2']`

Comment: @splash58 опубликуйте свой комментарий как ответ, я тогда свой ответ удалю. вы, все-таки, раньше ответили на 36 секунд :)

Comment: @strawdog да какая разница :) . вы лучше напишите, что при таком подходе, если нужной строки во второй таблице не будет, значение всё равно заменится, только на NaN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.loc[df["column1"] == "name1", "column2"] = df2.loc[df2["column1"] == "name1", "column2"]
```